# Why does combining background independence and diffeomorphism invariance force you to conclude that spacetime must be quantized?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, quantum-gravity, discrete, loop-quantum-gravity

I was recently watching a fermilab video on loop quantum gravity and at about 4:20 it is stated that, when combined, background independence and diffeomorphism invariance force you to conclude that spacetime is quantized. Why?